# Bash Back to run script

Tags: bash

i want to make an config script.

The main Script starts with "start.sh"
If the Script starts i can choose "install" "update" etc.

Now i want add "Config" and add content like php congigs like upload size....
But how i can go back to the start.sh? I want use parent id but im not sure how i can make it correct.

1. Start.sh

1.2 > Config

1.3 >> runs php_config.sh"

Now i want go back to "Start.sh" without run "start.sh" again. The vars i change would be written in a file and are global readable from start.sh > installer

Thank oyu

Edit: Sorry for bad quick asking...

i start the start.sh and install dialog and make a menu.
If the user choose "Make 2" i load the file and start the function.

```
#!/bin/bash

#-------------dialog
apt-get -qq install dialog >/dev/null 2>&1


HEIGHT=30
WIDTH=60
CHOICE_HEIGHT=14
BACKTITLE="How to get back"
TITLE="Back"
MENU="Choose one of the following options:"

        OPTIONS=(1 "Make 1"
                 2 "Make 2"
                 3 "Make 3")

        CHOICE=$(dialog --clear \
                        --nocancel \
                        --no-cancel \
                        --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
                        --title "$TITLE" \
                        --menu "$MENU" \
                        $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
                        "${OPTIONS[@]}" \
                        2>&1 >/dev/tty)

        clear
        case $CHOICE in
                1)
                    # Make 1
                    ;;
                1)
                    # Make 2
source ${SCRIPT_PATH}/menu_php_7_x.sh; php_7_x_config
                    ;;
                1)
                    # Make 3
                    ;;

        esac
```

The menu_php_7_x.sh is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
php_7_x_config() {

HEIGHT=30
WIDTH=60
CHOICE_HEIGHT=6
BACKTITLE="config php"
TITLE="Choose php.ini config"
MENU="Choose one of the following options:"

    OPTIONS=(1 "Change post_max_size"
                2 "Change upload_max_filesize"
                3 "Change memory_limit"
            )

    CHOICE=$(dialog --clear \
                    --nocancel \
                    --no-cancel \
                    --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
                    --title "$TITLE" \
                    --menu "$MENU" \
                    $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
                    "${OPTIONS[@]}" \
                    2>&1 >/dev/tty)

    clear
    case $CHOICE in
            1)
                CHOICE_HEIGHT=2
                MENU="Change post_max_size"

                            post_max_size=$(dialog --clear \
                                    --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
                                    --inputbox "Please Type your post_max_size value:" \
                                    $HEIGHT $WIDTH \
                                    3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- \
                                    )
                ;;

                2)
                CHOICE_HEIGHT=2
                MENU="Change upload_max_filesize"

                            upload_max_filesize=$(dialog --clear \
                                    --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
                                    --inputbox "Please Type your upload_max_filesize value:" \
                                    $HEIGHT $WIDTH \
                                    3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- \
                                    )
                ;;

                3)
                CHOICE_HEIGHT=2
                MENU="Change memory_limit"

                            memory_limit=$(dialog --clear \
                                    --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
                                    --inputbox "Please Type your memory_limit value:" \
                                    $HEIGHT $WIDTH \
                                    3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- \
                                    )
                ;;

    esac
    # Back to menu
    start.sh
}
```

This is only an example i want make the config with more options and pre  selections or the user have choose from selection and have not input a value.

My questions is now how i can go back to the script to let the user runs installation.

Comment: Please read what makes an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here. Then modify the question accordingly. Good luck `:-)`

Comment: Maybe take a look at [dialog](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_dialog.php)